# Java get month string from integer

Tags: java, date

Is there a better way to compact this method i.e. reduce the cyclomatic complexity by avoid the switch cases?

```
String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";       break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";      break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";         break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";         break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";           break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";          break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";          break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";        break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";       break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";      break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";      break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month"; break;
        }
        System.out.println(monthString);
```

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Try:

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
monthString = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month-1];
```

Alternatively, you could use SimpleDateFormat:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(date));
```

(You'll have to put a date with your month in a `Date` object to use the second option).

Comment: I think OP doesn't have date object. OP has integer as an index.

Comment: +1, for the first option. But it should be `new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month -1]`. Forgot to add `new` keyword.

Comment: DateFormatSymbols implementation was changed in JDK 8, so getMonths method doesn't return correct values for all Locale's anymore: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 25):

## `Month` enum

You could use the [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum. This enum is defined as part of the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

```
int monthNumber = 10;
Month.of(monthNumber).name();
```

The output would be:

> OCTOBER

### Localize

Localize to a language beyond English by calling [`getDisplayName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) on the same Enum.

```
String output = Month.OCTOBER.getDisplayName ( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

output:

> octobre

Comment: This Answer works only for English, the language used by the Java team in defining that enum. Is there any way to localize this string?

Comment: This [Month](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#enum.constant.summary) enum is only supporting the English name of month as per given in enum list. However, if you want to work with localize then there is available one method named with [getDisplayName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) where you can get support for locale.

Comment: This method works the only caveat is it needs minimum operating system Oreo(O).

Answer (score 9):

Take an array containing months name.

```
String[] str = {"January",      
   "February",
   "March",        
   "April",        
   "May",          
   "June",         
   "July",         
   "August",       
   "September",    
   "October",      
   "November",     
   "December"};
```

Then where you want to take month use as follows:

```
if(i<str.length)
    monthString = str[i-1];
else
    monthString = "Invalid month";
```

Comment: At first I thought this solution is silly (compared to Andrew), but right now I think it's good. Because I need foreign months names, and "new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month-1]" returns only local String.

Answer (score 3):

You could have an array of strigs and access by index.

```
  String months[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April",
                     "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                     "October", "November", "December"};
```

Answer (score 2):

This has already been mentioned, but here is a way to place the code within a method:

```
    public static String getMonthName(int monthIndex) {
         return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[monthIndex].toString();
    }
```

or if you wanted to create a better error than an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
    public static String getMonthName(int monthIndex) {
        //since this is zero based, 11 = December
        if (monthIndex < 0 || monthIndex > 11 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(monthIndex + " is not a valid month index.");
        }
        return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[monthIndex].toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.time.Month;

Month exemple = new Month.of(12);
//---return a Month object with value of December---

String month = exemple.toString();
//---if you want to convert Month to String---
```

Comment: (a) This was covered by the [Answer by Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32944451/642706). How does your Answer add value? (b) Your call to `toString` results in all-uppercase name of month such as `JANUARY`. The Questions asks for initial-cap, `January`. Better to use the automatic localization feature `getDisplayName` shown in [that other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32944451/642706). (c) Stack Overflow is more than a code snippet library. Answers are expected to have some discussion/explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**DateFormatSymbols** class provides methods for our ease use.

To get short month strings. For example: "Jan", "Feb", etc.

```
getShortMonths()
```

To get month strings. For example: "January", "February", etc.

```
getMonths()
```

Sample code to return month string in mmm format,

```
private static String getShortMonthFromNumber(int month){
    if(month<0 || month>11){
        return "";
    }
    return new DateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths()[month];
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see this is already in two of the other answers including the accepted and top voted one. What new are you contributing? Also this is the old-fashioned way. The modern way uses `Month.getDisplayName()` as in [the answer by Abhishek Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32944451/5772882).

Comment: getShortMonths() & getMonths() works for lower versions.  Also, added comment to make aware of getShortMonths() method to get  short values.