# How to get the month from a combobox and make it a month in a date

Tags: java, swing, date, combobox, jframe

I am making an application form that has dates on it and the person can enter the date through 3 separate comboboxes. I know how to convert the selected item to an int for the day and year to put into the LocalDate but I don't know an efficent way to do the months without a whole pile of if statements.

Here is the list:

```
private static String[] months = {"Month", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
```

Here is the comboboxes:

```
JComboBox startDateD = new JComboBox(days);
    JComboBox startDateM = new JComboBox(months);
    JComboBox startDateY = new JComboBox(years);
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is `LocalDate` from Java 8 (`java.time.LocalDate`)? Also, it's not clear what you're trying to do: get day, month and year (`int` values) and create a `LocalDate` or get the values from the date? Or something else?

Comment: What im trying to do is to get the month from the combo box to go to the likes of Month.JANUARY

Comment: `Month.of(combo.getSelectedIndex())` - value of selected index must be from 1 (January) to 12 (December), otherwise you'll get an exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have to create a month class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950994/i-have-to-create-a-month-class-in-java) - or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5799140/7605325) too

Comment: Consider using a [`SpinnerDateModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerDateModel.html) in a [`JSpinner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html) control..

Answer (score 1):

You need a listener (the `addActionListener`) and get the source inside the override method `actionPerformed`...

use this example as a guide (note that Month enum requires java8):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame someFrame = new JFrame();
    someFrame.setTitle("JComboBox Months");
    someFrame.setSize(250, 250);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JComboBox<Month> jcombo = new JComboBox<>(Month.values());
    panel.add(jcombo);
    jcombo.addActionListener(e -> {
        Month selMonth = (Month) ((JComboBox<Month>) e.getSource()).getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println(selMonth);
    });
    someFrame.add(panel);
    someFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```